# can we apply one background to multiple artboards in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, background, artboard

my question is specific to adobe artboards. i have 4 artboards of same dimensions of 1080px by 1080px. now i want to take only 1 background image that will split into all artboards.

generally all artboards have their own backgrounds separately.

this image will explain what i want ?? [image: artb]

i have searched everywhere but having no luck to found the exact answer. help will highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: why do you want that? that's not what artboards are for. Are you trying to do some sort of collage?

Comment: @Luciano actually i want to create multiple banners for social media that will looks like one banner as a whole (above image explain also). so instead of creation separately files, artboards makes it easy to design multiple objects in 1 psd file. and the other reason is that i have to use only 1 background that will split in all banners. let me know if further assistance required. thanks

Comment: You're aware that each Artboard gets exported to a separate image file, right?

Comment: @Luciano offcourse i am ... and when i export , the artboard will have it's background part.

Comment: I added an answer below. Wait a few more days to see if someone else has a different answer before marking it as accepted. Check [ask] and take the [tour] to learn more about the site.

Comment: Came across this article while searching for an answer with similar scenarios. This might help! https://photoshoptrainingchannel.com/instagram-seamless-panoramas-photoshop/

Answer (score 2):

I'm affraid you can't find an answer because there isn't one. Artboards don't work like that, you have to do it manually (or automate it with an Action).

1. get an image large enough to cover the length of your artboards (it seems you already have that)
2. add the image on the first artboard, convert it to a Smart Object*. align it to the left (0,0)
3. add the Smart Object to the second artboard, move it right by the pixel width of the previous artboard
4. repeat until you have no more artboards to cover.

If you want one continuous banner that *just looks like* split images you could use a layer mask with 4 shapes as the mask.

**Why use Smart Objects?* When you decide to use a different background you can simply edit the Smart Object and your background will already be aligned in the different Artboards.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my english I'm from Costa Rica. But It's easy you just have to put your background image out of any artboard (like a background layer) and when you export your files in the export option, just clik "include overlaping areas".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you figured this out yet, but I just ran into the same issue you were having in trying to create a carousel post for Instagram.

1. Set up three or more artboards in photoshop with a 1080x1080 size and move them right next to each other.
2. drop your image to the on top layer outside of artboards and convert to smart object
3. size your image to span across all artboards. This will set the size.
4. Then, duplicate this smart object and copy into each artboard.
5. Align images so it spans evenly across all artboards. They should snap right to alignment.
6. Finally go to (export as) and you can export your spanned background.